# Where can I get a proper dataset for performing Normalization techniques?

Tags: mysql, normalization, mysql-workbench

I'm new to databases and I just started with learning different techniques of Data Warehousing. I was given an assignment to perform Normalization techniques on a dataset of at least 1000 rows with minimum of three tables.

I'm not able to find any such data for the same.

I tried data.world, kaggle and uci but all in vain. Also, can I perform the normalization techniques using MySQL Workbench? Please help me out.

Comment: The only one I know (right off) is the `BEER` table by ThatJeffSmith (that's his name here on DBA SE). But, the denormalization process in his blog article uses SQL Developer on Oracle RDBMS.  You *might* be able to import the data (but not the tables into MySQL RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKutz I'll take a look

Comment: "Can I perform" Yes. What is stopping you? (Rhetorical.) Was that even the question you want answered? (Rhetorical.) (Yes-or-no questions are not helpful.) But please ask just 1 question per post. and please don't ask us to rewrite a textbook. Ask re where you are 1st stuck following one. PS Asking for off-site resources is also off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Percona's tpcc-mysql](https://github.com/Percona-Lab/tpcc-mysql). Here you can generate a dataset of any size. It should do what you ask.

Comment: Thanks @akuzminsky..But this one's for creating own data..I'm actually looking for a readily available dataset to perform some operations.

Comment: hm... maybe Sakila(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) or Employees database (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/). But they're normalized already.

Comment: there are few more sample databases https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Comment: Thank you so much..Will look into them